# Are both index.html and index.js needed?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, web-applications

I am learning about react, node.js in an application, I am doing in a group. The project has some restricted guidelines but my question is about whether index.html and index.js are needed together.

I have an index.html file already, but I want to create an index.js as well. 
Is this helpful or only one would be necessary? My group thinks I need it, I just don't understand why.

Comment: If you use WebPack to compile js files, you need to set the entry js file in WebPack's config file , which is used to be named as `index.js`, but it is not necessary.

Comment: ok. I do use webpack. But index.js would not be similar to index.html, correct (as far as code)?

Comment: index.js and index.html do not have a direct relationship. index.html‘s script  needs to import the final compiled js file , maybe called bundle.js, instead of index.js.